# How does the power consumption and cooling capacity of a Peltier refrigerator change when the interior is made reflective?

Tags: efficiency, peltier, cooling

I've a small Peltier cooler which I used to store some chemical stuffs. So, I recently modded the design to make it more bigger and improve its cooling + insulation.

I've added an aluminium piece plate as the base which is in contact with the cold part of the Peltier, the other four sides are covered with thermocole. I keep it running 24x7 on my atx power supply. I have installed a refrigerator gas expansion thermostat in it to turn-off once it is sufficiently cool inside(-1C to 0C).

My question is how does the cooling change if I stick aluminum tape on the inside of the thermocole insulation (interior of the cooling cabin) and make it reflective? Will it increase the cooling capacity and reduce the power-on time?

**Note:** I've posted it here since most of the Peltier questions are here. If this is the wrong forum please guide me move it to the appropriate forum.Thanks.

Comment: move it to physics.se

Comment: thermal energy or heat can be conducted and radiated. But here conducted offers lower thermal resistance. So you want to maximize heat transfer on both sides hot and cold to maximize the differential and flow of energy with the best insulation in between both heat exchangers to improve efficiency. Aluminum tape is rather thin to be a good conductor but bettern than just thermal insulation . consider an external motor driven axle with air impellers inside and out to improve heat exchanger flow. this is an electro-mechanical problem for an EE to learn ME skills.

Comment: Adding a reflective inner layer increases effective cooling - but maybe not by much. Reflection stops thermal energy getting TO the walls. Insulation stops it getting through the walls. As Tony says an air impeller inside helps BUT should be driven mechanically from outside so that heat energy is not added by a fan motor. Internal fan makes internal gas closer to Peltier cold plate temperature and/or lowers the thermal resistance coefficient of the Peltier cold side.